# Login Redirect in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page which a require users to login to view the page. I've used the following code from [Link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83403/using-auth-redirect-keeps-asking-me-to-login-even-when-im-loggen-in). The issue however is when the user logs in, he is taken to the home page rather than the page he was trying to visit. How can i solve this?

```
add_action('template_redirect','wpse16975_check_if_logged_in');
function wpse16975_check_if_logged_in(){
$pageid = 2295;
if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page($pageid)) {
$url = add_query_arg(
    'redirect_to',
    get_permalink($pageid),
    site_url('wp-login.php')
);
wp_redirect($url);
exit;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_login_url()`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url

Change this:

```
$url = add_query_arg(
    'redirect_to',
    get_permalink($pageid),
    site_url('wp-login.php'));
```

To:

```
$url = wp_login_url( get_permalink( $pageid ) );
```

A similar URL will be assigned to the `$url` variable but the redirect_to parameter will be run through `urlencode()` first.